# Upgrade project created with 0.61.5 with react native to 0.68.2

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting such an error while upgrading the application, can you help me?

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> Native libs debug enabled: false
> Android gradle plugin: 7.0.4
> Gradle: 7.3.3
> building Reanimated2

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: [CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 49s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: [CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 49s

```
at makeError (E:\reactnativeproject\upgradedapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at E:\reactnativeproject\upgradedapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\reactnativeproject\upgradedapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\reactnativeproject\upgradedapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Install cmake from Android Studio's SDK Manager.

Click Tools > SDK Manager, click the SDK Tools tab, check CMake then click OK.